# Is there a limit to how much quarried stone you can mine?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I just installed the DLC, bought Lakeview Manor, and now I have to furnish the inside. It seems that I can only find a few quarry stones in the chest and next to a hill, but on the hill was a stone quarry vein.

[image: STONE!]

So I mined it. It took forever and ever and I tried to wait before it depletes. It didn't. Here are my theories:

- The quarry gives you a huge amount of quarried stone before depletion.
- The quarry give you unlimited amounts of quarried stone, so you won't have to find another vein.

So which theory is true? Is there a limit to how much quarried stone can be mined? Or does it go forever until you press a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mine 4000 units before depletion.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Quarried_Stone

> This material is mined with a pickaxe from sources called "Stone Quarry" found throughout Skyrim. These sources can yield 4000 units each before depleting.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that in a specific set of in-game time, resources will "replenish" themselves.